# The conditions in the definition of Brownian motion

Tags: pr.probability, stochastic-processes

A (standard, real-valued) Brownian motion $W = \{W(t): t \geq 0\}$ is commonly defined   by the following properties: 1) $W(0) = 0$ a.s., 2)  the process has independent increments, 3) for all $s,t \geq 0$ with $s<t$,  the increment $W(t) – W(s)$ is normally distributed with mean zero and variance $t-s$,  and 4) almost surely, the function $t \mapsto W(t)$ is continuous.

As is well known, the above set of conditions can be reduced to 2), 3') for all $t \geq 0$, $W(t)$ has mean zero  and variance $t$, and 4). [Note that, in 3'), $W(t)$ is not assumed   to be normally distributed.]  But what about omitting condition 2)? Can you find an   example of a process $W$ satisfying conditions 1), 3),  and 4), but not 2)? [Note that such $W$ must have (the Brownian motion)   covariance $E[W(s)W(t)] = s$, $0 \leq s \leq t$; hence, it cannot be a Gaussian process,  for otherwise it would be a Brownian motion.]

Comment: A special case that might be useful to consider first: if $X$ and $Y$ are separately normally distributed and uncorrelated, and $X+Y$ is also normally distributed, must $(X,Y)$ be jointly normally distributed?  

Comment: Nate - The answer to that is no. The answer to the original question is no, W need not be a BM. I have a (slightly messy) construction of a counterexample in mind, which I'll post when I have a few moments free.

Comment: @George Lowther: Great, I will be interested to see it.  If one can answer my question more generally with $n$ random variables, then one could probably plug the resulting joint distributions into Kolmogorov's extension theorem and produce a counterexample to the original question.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

No, it is not true that a process *W* satisfying the properties (1), (3) and (4) has to be a Brownian motion. We can construct a counter-example as follows.

This construction is rather contrived, and I don't know if there's any simple examples.
Start with a standard Brownian motion *W*. The idea is to apply a small bump to its distribution while retaining the required properties. I will do this by first reducing it to the discrete-time case. So, choose a finite sequence of times 0 = *t*<sub>0</sub> < *t*<sub>1</sub> < ... < *t*<sub>*n*</sub>. Then define a piecewise linear process *X* by *X*<sub>*t*<sub>*k*</sub></sub> = *W*<sub>*t*<sub>*k*</sub></sub> (*k* = 0,1,...,*n*) and such that *X* is linearly interpolated across each of the intervals [*t*<sub>*k*-1</sub>,*t*<sub>*k*</sub>] and constant over [*t*<sub>*n*</sub>,∞).

Then, *Y* = *W* - *X* is a continuous process independent from *X*. In fact, *Y* is just a sequence of [Brownian bridges](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Brownian_bridge) across the intervals [*t*<sub>*k*-1</sub>,*t*<sub>*k*</sub>] and is a standard Brownian motion on [*t*<sub>*n*</sub>,∞). Also by linear interpolation, for any time *t* ≥ 0, *X*<sub>*t*</sub> is a linear combination of at most two of the random variables *X*<sub>*t*<sub>1</sub></sub>,...,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>*n*</sub></sub>. The increments of *W*,
$$
W_t-W_s = X_t-X_s + Y_t-Y_s,
$$
are then a linear combination of at most 4 of the random variables *X*<sub>*t*<sub>1</sub></sub>,...,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>*n*</sub></sub> plus an independent term. So, choosing *n* ≥ 5, if it is possible to replace (*X*<sub>*t*<sub>1</sub></sub>,...,*X*<sub>*t*<sub>*n*</sub></sub>) by any other ℝ<sup>n</sup>-valued random variable without changing the joint-distribution of any 4 elements, then the distributions of the increments *W*<sub>*t*</sub> - *W*<sub>*s*</sub> will be left unchanged. So, properties (1), (3), (4) will still be satisfied but the new process for *W* will not be a standard Brownian motion. It is possible to change the distribution in this way:

> Let *X* = (*X*<sub>1</sub>,*X*<sub>2</sub>,...,*X*<sub>*n*</sub>) be an ℝ<sup>n</sup>-valued random variable with a continuous and strictly positive probability density *p*<sub>*X*</sub>: ℝ<sup>n</sup> → ℝ. Then, there exists a random variable *Y* = (*Y*<sub>1</sub>,*Y*<sub>2</sub>,...,*Y*<sub>*n*</sub>) with a different distribution than *X* but for which the projection onto any *n* - 1 elements has the same distribution as for *X*.

That is, for any *k*<sub>1</sub>,*k*<sub>2</sub>,...,*k*<sub>*n*-1</sub> in {1,...,*n*}, (*Y*<sub>*k*<sub>1</sub></sub>,*Y*<sub>*k*<sub>2</sub></sub>,...,*Y*<sub>*k*<sub>*n*-1</sub></sub>) has the same distribution as (*X*<sub>*k*<sub>1</sub></sub>,*X*<sub>*k*<sub>2</sub></sub>,...,*X*<sub>*k*<sub>*n*-1</sub></sub>).

We can construct the probability density *p*<sub>*Y*</sub> of *Y* by applying a bump to the probability distribution of *X*,
$$
p_Y(x)=p_X(x)+\epsilon f(x_1)f(x_2)\cdots f(x_n).
$$
Here, ε is a fixed real number and *f*: ℝ → ℝ is a continuous function of compact support and zero integral, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty f(x)\,dx=0$. Then, $\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_Y(x)\,dx_k=\int_{-\infty}^\infty p_X(x)\,dx_k$ for each *k*. So, the integral of *p*<sub>*Y*</sub> over ℝ<sup>*n*</sup> is 1 and, by choosing ε small, *p*<sub>*Y*</sub> will be positive. Then it is a valid probability density function. Finally, as the integral along the *k*<sup>th</sup> direction (any *k*) agrees for *p*<sub>*X*</sub> and *p*<sub>*Y*</sub>, the projection of *X* and *Y* onto ℝ<sup>*n*-1</sup> along the *k*<sup>th</sup> direction give the same distribution.

Comment: Actually, this argument shows that for any n, there is a continuous process whose distribution agrees with a standard Brownian motion at any set of n times, but is not a BM.

Answer (score 0):

Hi,

No you can't, because (1-3-4) implies that $W_t$ is a continuous martingale with quadratic variation equals to $t$ so by a very well known Lévy's Theorem, it has to be a Brownian Motion.

Regards

Comment: Why does it have to be a martingale?

Comment: you are right, my mistake, the constancy of expactation of $W_t$ is not enough it should hold for all finite stopping time to hold which I cannot prove. 

Comment: For Lévy's theorem you only need it to be a local martingale. 